# jquery datatables : Unable to get property 'fnFilter' of undefined or null reference

Tags: jquery, datatable, datatables

I am using jquery datatable in my application. Below is my JS.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    configureSearchDataTable(); 
    bindSearchEvents();     
});

function bindSearchEvents(){
    $('#searchBtn').bind('click',function(event) {          
        var searchCriteriaDelimiter = "#";                                          
        searchResultsTable.fnFilter($('#Name').val()+searchCriteriaDelimiter+$('#Id').val());
        $('#searchResults').show();                 
    });
}

var searchResultsTable;
function configureSearchDataTable(){    
    searchResultsTable = $("#searchResultsTable").dataTable({
        "bServerSide": true,
        "sAjaxSource": "allSearchAjaxResults.form",
        "bProcessing": false,       
        "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
        "oLanguage": {"sEmptyTable": "No data available", "sLengthMenu" :" _MENU_ items per page",
        "sInfo": "Showing _START_ to _END_ of _TOTAL_ records",
        "sInfoEmpty": "No entries to show"},
        "sDom": 'tlip',
        "aoColumns": [{ "bVisible": false },null,null,null,{ "bVisible": false }]
    });
}
```

its giving error as "Unable to get property 'fnFilter' of undefined or null reference" on page load. Not sure whats wrong here.

Thanks

Comment: Can you check if searchResultsTable  is null after the command "searchResultsTable = $("#searchResultsTable").dataTable({..."

Comment: I am getting error before it comes to configureSearchDataTable() function. I am getting error in the line "searchResultsTable.fnFilter($(..." in bindSearchEvents() function on page load.

Answer (score 0):

As you said you arrived to the function `bindSearchEvents` before calling to the function `configureSearchDataTable` This mean, the variable `searchResultsTable` never initialized (`searchResultsTable` is `null`). When trying `null.anything` we will get an error `Unable to get property 'anything'`.

My guess you have another place you calling to the function `bindSearchEvents` put break point in the function and check where it called from.

Comment: Thanks for the reply :).. I found the root cause. I had only three headers in the table -searchResultsTable. though I have made the first column data not to display, still it expects header to be defined for that. adding a header to the table did the trick.